# Storing output of a nested loop as new array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, output

I need to find the largest prime number of a given array when adding two numbers in an array,so I decided to add all possible sums first and displayed it. Now I want to take those output elements to a new array.Please help me solve this problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int noOfElem = scanner.nextInt();
            int[] array = new int[noOfElem];
            int[][] newArray = new int[5][4];
            int i=0;
            while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
                i++;
                if(i == noOfElem){
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
            {
                for (int b = a+1; b < array.length; b++) {
                    int m = array[a] + array[b];
                    newArray[a][b] = 
                }
            }
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what the problem is here, just do

```
newArray[a][b] = m;
```

This stores all sums of all 'a's and 'b's such that newArray[a][b] is the sum of array[a] + array[b]